# C# login a webpage without opening it

Tags: c#, wpf, web

everyone

I am looking for a idea that helps me to solve my problem. I am trying to create a wpf programm which i could login on a webpage with given username and password in WPF, after that i could also get a successed message.

I have tried with following code:

**Xaml file:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
        <TextBox x:Name="username" Width="200" Margin="2,2,10,2" Text="username"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="password" Width="200" Margin="2,2,10,2" Text="password"/>
        <Button Width="200" Content="Go!" Margin="2" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" >
        <WebBrowser x:Name="wb1" Height="500" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="state" Text="Connection" ></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Code Behinde:**

```
...

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        wb1.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(bws_LoadCompleted);
        wb1.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(bws_Navigated);

    }

           void bws_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HideScriptErrors(wb1, true);
    }

    void bws_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Uri.AbsolutePath)
        {
            case "/":
                DoExample1();
                break;
            case "/login":
                DoExample1();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void DoExample1()
    {
        TryFillInBing(username.Text, password.Text);

    }

    void TryFillInBing(string name, string passwd)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            if (!LoginInput(0, "username", "password", name, passwd) && Tries < 6)
            {
                Tries++;
                TryFillInBing(name, passwd);
            }
            else
            {
                IHTMLFormElement form = GetForm(0);
                form.submit();
            }
        }));
    }

    private bool UpdateTextInput(int formId, string name, string text)
    {
        bool successful = false;
        IHTMLFormElement form = GetForm(formId);
        if (form != null)
        {
            var element = form.item(name: name);
            if (element != null)
            {
                var textinput = element as HTMLInputElement;
                textinput.value = text;
                successful = true;
            }
        }

        return successful;
    }

    private bool LoginInput(int formId, string name, string passwd, string text, string pw)
    {
        bool successful = false;
        IHTMLFormElement form = GetForm(formId);
        if (form != null)
        {
            var element = form.item(name);
            var pass = form.item(passwd);

            if (element != null && pass != null)
            {
                var textinput = element as HTMLInputElement;
                textinput.value = text;
                var passinput = pass as HTMLInputElement;
                passinput.value = pw;

                successful = true;
            }
        }
        return successful;
    }
```

...
...
...

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string conquerclubLogin = "https://www.conquerclub.com";
        string googleWeb = "http://www.google.de";

        wb1.Navigate(conquerclubLogin);
    }
```

But it showed me the same login page and i did not receive any message for successfull login...Has anyone an idea for me?

Cheers, Carvin

Comment: you put values in the name and password I dont see  you submit them

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for answering me! In this funktion i have called submit() `else
            {
                IHTMLFormElement form = GetForm(0);
                form.submit();
            }`

Comment: but only either tries to put values in OR submits it - it doesnt do both... and each time you load the page you are trying again.. so. I dont think submit is ever called unless placing values didnt work then it can submit it...

Comment: @BugFinder thanks. I am thinking wrong...what i want is that i can login a web page without opening it...could you show me a example or more tips?